# Regarding scheduled actions in process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have a requirement to send an email after x days when status changes to y
Meanwhile if the status has changed to another value ,can i stop the scheduled email delivery after x days ?

I am using process builder...

Answer (score 2):

As per Salesforce docs:

> **Will the pending actions in the queue ALWAYS trigger?** No. Time-dependent actions remain in the Workflow Queue until processed or
>   the rule criteria for the Workflow Rule are evaluated as "false." If a
>   record no longer matches the rule criteria when the rule is evaluated,
>   Salesforce removes the time-dependent actions queued for that record.

I never tested this with PB but I think PB should give same output as well. So, in this case, you don't need to do anything Salesforce already handle it.

[Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for the record from the queue. As per the salesforce documentation related to How Does Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions?

> **What Happens When the Field Values Change?**
>
> - For processes that start when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for
>     those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the
>     criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for the record from
>     the queue.
> - For processes that start when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record with that process. Scheduled actions remain in
>     the queue, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria
>     when the scheduled actions are executed.
> - If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with
>     the field. For example, a process is configured to email an
>     opportunity owner 7 days before the opportunity close date. The close
>     date is set to 2/20/2014. Salesforce processes the schedule on
>     2/13/2014 and sends the email. If the close date is later updated to
>     2/10/2014 and the schedule hasn’t been processed yet, Salesforce
>     recalculates the schedule and sends the email on 2/3/2014. If
>     Salesforce recalculates the schedule to a date in the past, it
>     executes the associated actions shortly after you save the record.
> - If the record or object that the schedule is associated with is deleted, Salesforce never processes the schedule.

For more details go through [Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5)